# FET amplifier (Av=?)

Tags: voltage, mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier

[image: that's the original circuit]How to find Vo of this pi model of FET amplifier? 
[image]
I have to find voltage amplification (Av=Vo/Vi) of this circuit and output resistance Ro, so I need to find the Vo voltage. I found the expression for current id, but I don't know how to express Vo.
Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

(id-gm1Vgs1)rd1 + idRs1 + (id-gm2Vgs2)rd2 + idRs2=0

(id -gm1(Vi-idRs1))rd1 + idRs1 + (id-gm2(Vi-idRs2))rd2 +idRs2=0

if the calculation are made

**id= (gm1rd1 +gm2rd2)Vi / rd1+rd2+Rs1+Rs2+gm1Rs1rd1+gm2Rs2rd2**

*this is the original circuit*

[image: that's the original circuit]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNkDcM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: @DerStrom8  I edited the post

Comment: Are you sure both transistors are PMOS transistors? I have a small hunch that M2 needs to be an NMOS transistor, else the bulk-source PN junction will start conducting.

Comment: Also, I believe that in your small-signal equivalent circuit, your transconductance \$g_{m1}V_{gs1}\$ is pointed the wrong way.

Comment: @SvenB  I uploaded the original circuit, too. Indeed, I am not clear if the transistors are NMOS or PMOS.                                         Shouldn't gm1Vgs1 be directed from drain to source?

Comment: They should. But your schematic is saying pmos, which makes the drain the output voltage and source Vdd. Your picture uses a rather strange symbol. It looks like a mix of JFET and NMOS. I still don't know if it is CMOS or something else...

Comment: Your small signal equivalent circuit on the photo is saying NMOS for the bottom transistor, PMOS for the top.

Comment: If I write the Kirchhoff Voltage law , there is:                (id-gm1Vgs1)rd1 + idRs1 + (id-gm2Vgs2)rd2 + idRs2=0                                                                                        So if Vgs2= Vi - idRs2,  how about Vgs1?